# Why do the soft QCD processes have non-perturbative nature?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

I know that due to their non-perturbative nature, soft (i.e. low momentum transfer) QCD processes require phenomenological models that need to be tuned to data. However, I do not exactly understand why these processes are non-perturbative. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: You do appreciate why high momentum transfer ones are perturbative, instead?

Comment: Have you read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics and particularly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Methods

Comment: Related: [Why does QCD become strongly interacting at low energies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516221/why-does-qcd-become-strongly-interacting-at-low-energies-and-how-low-is-low-here)